# hazelcast maven dependencies not found in my project?

Tags: spring, hibernate, maven, spring-boot, hazelcast

Am trying to add below hazelcast maven dependencies to my spring boot project pom.xml , but it is saying dependencies not found .

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.hazelcast</groupId>
            <artifactId>hazelcast</artifactId>
            <version>3.7.5</version>
        </dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.hazelcast</groupId>
    <artifactId>hazelcast-hibernate5</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

but my pom.xml complaining that those dependencies not found by highlighting the version numbers

[here](http://collabedit.com/v5xj5) the link to my complete pom.xml

can anyone please help me on this .

Comment: Looking at maven central those don't appear to be the *latest* versions of those libraries, but they are valid, existing versions.

Comment: do you have some proxy setup in your network? Are you trying to get them in a corporate office with a proxy?

Comment: I tried exactly your dependencies and it works fine, so it must be something related to your network or Maven Central repo configuration.

Answer (score 1):

In case of the following issues

```sh
Could not resolve com.hazelcast:hazelcast-enterprise-all:4.1.1.
         > Could not get resource 'https://dl.bintray.com/hazelcast/release/com/hazelcast/hazelcast-enterprise-all/4.1.1/hazelcast-enterprise-all-4.1.1.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://dl.bintray.com/hazelcast/release/com/hazelcast/hazelcast-enterprise-all/4.1.1/hazelcast-enterprise-all-4.1.1.pom'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
```

or

```sh
Could not resolve com.hazelcast:hazelcast-enterprise-all:4.1.1.
         > Could not get resource 'https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com/hazelcast/hazelcast-enterprise-all/4.1.1/hazelcast-enterprise-all-4.1.1.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com/hazelcast/hazelcast-enterprise-all/4.1.1/hazelcast-enterprise-all-4.1.1.pom'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
```

Solved by adding repository URL

**build.gradle.kts**

```
repositories {
   maven(url = "https://repository.hazelcast.com/release/")
}
```

OR

```
maven {
   setUrl("https://repository.hazelcast.com/release")
   metadataSources {
        mavenPom()
        artifact()
   }
}
```

[Ref](https://docs.hazelcast.com/imdg/latest/installation/installing-using-maven.html)